Understanding the integral of a bounded operator on a Hilbert Space
In mathematical physics I've encountered the holomorphic functional calculus, which I've seen the defined as:
Let $f$ be holomorphic in a neighbourhood of the spectrum of $T$, with $T$ being a bounded operator on a Hilbert Space $H$. I've seen $f(T)$ defined as
$$f(T)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma f(\lambda)(\lambda I-T)^{-1}d\lambda$$
For some curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C}\backslash\sigma(T)$. I'm not sure what exactly is to be understood by the integral of a function that goes from $\mathbb{C}$ into $B(H)$ (the bounded linear operators on $H$). I know that the result of the integration should be an operator, and I can see the similarity with Cauchy's Integral Formula. But I'm not really sure what is meant by an integral of something that goes into $B(H)$.
Thanks in advance!

You can refer to Vector Measures by Diestel and Uhl for vector valued integration.
